# Instantiating each of the two classes in one another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, class, class-design

I have a C# class question which I hope to get some help with.  I have one class called CountdownUserControl.  There are a number of functions within this class.  I then have another class called Min.  There are certain things I need in this form within CountdownUserControl class so I create an instance of it within CountdownUserControl:

```
public partial class CountdownUserControl : UserControl
{
    //-----------------------------------------------
    // Private data members
    //-----------------------------------------------
    private Min _Min = new Min();
```

However within the Min class I also would like to use a function which is contained within the CountdownUserControl class - however I cannot create an instance of it within the Min class such as

```
public partial class Min : Form
{
    private CountdownUserControl CU = new CountdownUserControl();
```

so that within Min class I could do CU.Method_I_want();

as this will give a stackoverflow.  Does anyone know a solution around this?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why don't you put methods which are required in other classes in a third helper class?

Comment: Why the downvotes on the question? It doesn't seem deserved to me. It might be a basic question for some but that doesn't mean its a bad one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these answers are great, but you should also consider the fact that [cyclic dependencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) are generally really difficult to work with. Your classes should be somewhat isolated units with a [single purpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). They should be [loosely coupled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) from each other. If you redesign your classes to eliminate cyclic dependencies and follow these guidelines, you will write better and more maintainable code in general and will have less issues like this in the first place.

Comment: I have chosen this as my answer.  I have redisgned the complete classes and they appear to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

### Classes and methods

Classes shouldn't just been seen as a collection of methods, when they are created ('instantiated') with `new`, they become actual objects that should be treated as such.

You need to re-think your strategy and instead simply *reference* a `Min` or `CoundownUserControl` object.  What does each one represent?  You are suggesting that the `UserControl` (a part of a `Form`) needs to have its own `Form` created for it - that's not the case.  The `Form` is the object that *creates* the `UserControl`.  The `UserControl` can access the `Form` by using the `ParentForm` property.

### The StackOverflow

When you do this: `new Min()` you are creating a new `Min` object.  Then, in `Min`, when you do this: `new CountdownUserControl()` you are creating a new `CoundownUserControl` object.  Which in turn creates a new `Min` object, and so on and so forth.

### How to fix your problem

Simply put, use `Min min = (Min)this.ParentForm;` within the user control if you are sure the user control is on a `Form` whose type is `Min`.

And finally/additionally, you should not create the instance of `CountdownUserControl` yourself unless you are going to set the properties and add it to the `Controls` collection of the form within your code.  Instead, build your project, drag-and-drop the `CountdownUserControl` onto your form - a property to access the control will be created on your `Min` class automatically, called `countdownUserControl1`.

Answer (score 1):

There surely are plenty of solutions to this. An easy one would be to pass the current Min to CountdownUserControl in its constructor (or vice versa):

```
private Min min;
public CountdownUserControl(Min min)
{
     this.min = min;
}
```

When you are facing these kind of problems, there probably is something wrong with your class structure, though. Maybe you could split some of the functionality out of your classes into a new one to avoid this problem.

Comment: If the user control is being added to the form, there is no need to do this, since the user control can access the form via the `ParentForm` property

Comment: Hi Jen - what would then have to be placed in the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of instantiating a new Min class every time, you could set the value of it in a constructor.

```
public CountdownUserControl(Min min)
{
     _Min = min;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is CountdownUserControl going to be on the Form Min?  Why would you instantiate the form from the control, and not the reverse?  Shouldn't the Countdown control be on the form?  Then you could instantiate the form, initialize the control, and then access the function.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create a form in the user control. Add it as a dependency:

```
public partial class CountdownUserControl : UserControl
{
    private Min _Min;

    public CountdownUserControl(Min parentForm);
```

And then use it in your form:

```
public partial class Min : Form
{
    private CountdownUserControl CU;

    public Min()
    {
       CU = new CountdownUserControl (this);
    }
```

**Update**

A more suitable solution would be to break out the common functionality from the two classes and put them in separate classes. Read up on single responsibility principle. I got a post about it in my [blog](http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/07/single-responsibility-prinicple/).

Comment: Since it's a user control, it's more like the user control should be added to the form, not simply instantiated

Comment: Of course. But that detail was left out of the question, hence I left it out of the answer. `Controls.Add(CU)` or wherever he want's to place it.

Comment: In which case, why is it necessary to pass an instance of the container for to the user control?

Comment: Why create a new field and constructor when the existing `ParentForm` property for a `UserControl` exists for exactly this purpose?

Comment: Because he needs his `Min` form and not any form. Hence it's more proper to force a `Min` form by using the constructor.

Comment: @KierenJohnstone let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2319/discussion-between-jgauffin-and-kieren-johnstone)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in an instance of your CountdownUserControl to your Min class (via an additional constructor parameter or via a property).

```
public partial class Min: Form {
    public Min() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public CountdownUserControl Countdown {get;set;}
}
```

Since this is a form you probably want to go with the property so as not to break the designer.

I won't speak to whether or not this is proper form (hopefullt you are using something like PresentationModel or MVC), as I do know tehre are times code like this is required.

Now as has been pointed out, if you plan on showing the user control in the form then a different solution should be adopted. But it all depends on how you are planning on what you are doing with the form. If you are for example showing teh form in a dialog keeping a class level reference is a bad idea since once closed the form will be disposed.

A little more detail would get you closer to a fully correct answer.

Comment: So an external class should create an instance of a user control, then set a property on the form?  How will the control ever get added / displayed on the form?

Comment: Well this is the problem with the question. He wants to use a function on a user control in his form (he didn't mention showing the control in the form). It seems like behavior which as I mentions speaks to using MVC, PresentationModel, or some pattern which abstracts the view from its logic.

Comment: Also his example show's him newing up the form in the user control. In this case he may just want to show the form as the result of an event on the control the O.P. would have to specify more details to know.

Comment: The OP clearly has a user control, a form, and is trying to call a method on the form from a user control.  He is confused yes, and that is reflected in the question.  However, this is *not a good solution*.  If the control is added to the form, there is already a member for it - you could create a wrapper property, but it should not have a `set`.

Comment: I agree, however you are assuming the control is being added to the form, but the question doesn't state that. He does however new up the form from the control in his question.

Comment: So you're saying it's more likely that the OP has a strong grasp of how classes, forms and user controls work, and is intentionally and for good reason creating a form within a user control constructor?  Isn't it instead incredibly likely that he has a UC, a form, and simply wants to call a method on the form from within the UC?

Comment: Phil's answer get's to the root problem. If the user want's to share behavior between a Form and a UserControl there are vastly better solutions. I provided a manner of stopping the stackoverflow. It is not the only way.

Answer (score 0):

> However within the Min class I also would like to use a function which is contained within the CountdownUserControl class - however I cannot create an instance of it within the Min class such as

**Is it really necessary that mentioned function is member of CountdownUserControl?**

Could you reveal more of public interface of your classes?
If the function has no reference to instance of CountdownUserControl consider changing it to static. Else try to design new class named e.g. CountdownState whose instance may be shared among both CountdownUserControl and Min.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that whenever a `CountdownUserControl` is created, it tries to create a new `Min`, but whenever a new `Min` is created, it tries to create a new `CountdownUserControl`. This process could continue indefinitely and therefore the stack is blown.

The solution is to inject the instance of `CountdownUserControl` into `Min` (Or vice versa, depending on what gets created first).

So `CountdownUserControl` will look like this:

```
public partial class CountdownUserControl : UserControl
{
    //-----------------------------------------------
    // Private data members
    //-----------------------------------------------
    private Min _Min;

    public CountdownUserControl(Min min)
    {
        _Min = min;
    }
```

...and `Min` will look like this:

```
public partial class Min : Form
{
    private CountdownUserControl CU;

    public Min()
    {
        CU = new CountdownUserControl(this);
    }
```

Comment: You're suggesting that in the constructor for a user control, you create a `Form`?  Do you want to reconsider?

Comment: Yes you are correct Kieren - a little oversight from me. Answer edited. I am wondering now whether property injection is a better idea.